# AngularJS Directive doesn't update

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I develop a forum with Angular, and you can tag each discussion. In the discussion list, if you click on the tag, it will filter the discussion with this tag.

I use a directive for displaying the tag :

```
directive('tag', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        templateUrl: tagDirective,
        controller: 'TagController',
        controllerAs: 'tagCtrl',
        scope: {
            tagId: '@id'
        },
        replace:true
    }
})
```

The template :

```
<div class="tag" ng-click="tagCtrl.filterByTag(tagId)">
    {{ tagCtrl.tags[tagId].title }}
</div>
```

The controller :

```
controller("TagController", ["TagService", "ModelService", "$location", function(tag, model, $location){
    var ctrl = this;
    ctrl.tags = {};
    ctrl.tag = tag;

    model.getTags(function(datas){
        datas.forEach(function(item){
            ctrl.tags["tag"+item.id] = item;
        });
    });

    ctrl.filterByTag = function(id){
        tag.current = ctrl.tags[id];
        if($location.path() !== routes.index){
            $location.path(routes.index);
        }
    };
}])
```

And the service :

```
service('TagService', [function(){
    var serv = this;
    serv.current = {};
}])
```

Whenever where in the forum, when the user click on a tag, he is redirected to the index page (the list of all discussions).

The filtering tag used is "stored" in the service.

All of this seems to work : I can display the stored Tag, I'm redirected when I click a Tag (the filtering doesn't work yet bet it's an other problem).

My problem is when I want to display the Tag in the header :

```
<tag id="{{ 'tag'+headerCtrl.tag.current.id }}"></tag>
```

The header never display the tag title.

I tried this :

```
<tag id="{{ 'tag2' }}"></tag>
```

to force the displaying of the second tag (not the filtering, only displaying) and it doesn't work either...

Am I doing something wrong ?

Subsidiary : Am I using AngularJS in the right way ? Is there some best practices I doesn't used or misunderstood ?

Thank you !

Edit 1 :

I had the Header part :

Directive :

```
directive("forumHeader", function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        templateUrl: headerDirective,
        controller: 'HeaderController',
        controllerAs: 'headerCtrl',
        replace:true
    };
})
```

Html :

```
<header>
    <tag tid="{{ 'tag'+headerCtrl.tag.current.id }}"></tag>
</header>
```

Controller :

```
controller("HeaderController", ["TagService", "ModelService", function(tag, model){
    var ctrl = this;
    ctrl.tag = tag;
    ctrl.tags = [];

    model.getTags(function(datas){
        ctrl.tags = datas;
    });

    ctrl.colored = function(item){
        if(item.color) return true;
    };
}])
```

Comment: You might want to use a different attribute name, as `id` already has a meaning in HTML. When the browser sees the punctuation and spaces, it probably discards the attribute before Angular gets to see it.

Comment: I change the name to tagId, same problem. When I display a discussion, the tag works. It's only in the header that he doesn't show.

Comment: And what is inside headerCtrl? Does tag is defined correctly? Please show how do you user ng-controller directive for headerCtrl.

Answer (score 0):

The directive controller gets injected a scope and an element. You're not injecting those. `$scope.tagId` is where you grab the attribute value from (and use it in the template).

Comment: I never use the tagId in my controller. It doesn't solve the problem to inject the scope in my controller and the only place where i can get the element is the link function.

Answer (score 0):

I found a dirty solution...

The problem is here :

```
model.getTags(function(datas){
    datas.forEach(function(item){
        ctrl.tags["tag"+item.id] = item;
    });
});
```

And in the tempo of the application. For the service, if API call is running, I return the empty array that will be fill later. But here, I make a difference between the service array and the controller data structure. It doesn't work for the Tag header because the API call is running, so the array is empty.

To solve the problem, I tried in the first time to store in the controller and $scope.$watch the returning datas of the API calls and to redistribute in the controller object in the watch callback but the callback was called only once and not when the array is updated.

So I made a second Service function (getTagsObject) that return an object I store directly in the controller. It works but it's not very clean I think.

The problem was coming from my Service and not from the code I show here, sorry for the confusion. Here is the code of the service :

```
serv.getTags = function(callback){
    callback = callback || function(){};
    var tag;
    if(serv.tags.length === 0 && !tagsIndex["_running"]){
        tagsIndex["_running"] = true;
        $http.get(tagReadAll)
            .success(function(data){
                data.forEach(function(item){
                    initTag(item);
                });
                callback(serv.tags);
                tagsIndex["_running"] = false;
            })
            .error(function(data){
                tagsIndex["_running"] = false;
            });
    } else {
        callback(serv.tags);
    }
};

serv.getTagsObject = function(callback){
    if(serv.tags.length === 0) serv.getTags();
    callback(serv.tagsObj);
};
```

And the initTag function :

```
function initTag(data){
    var tag = $.extend({}, data);
    tagsIndex[tag.id] = tag;
    serv.tagsObj["tag"+tag.id] = tag;
    serv.tags.push(tag);
    return tag;
}
```